# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\sin a_i| +|\cos s_n|\ge 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, alternative-proof

> Let $a_i$ be a real sequence and $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ its sequence of partial sums. Prove that $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\sin a_i|\right)  +| \cos s_n|\ge 1$$

I have a proof by induction.

Let us take the base case $n=1$:

$$|\sin a_1|+|\cos a_1|\ge |\sin^2a_1|+|\cos^2a_1|=1$$

Assuming for n=k is true, it is sufficient to prove

$$|\sin a_{k+1}|+|\cos s_{k+1}|\ge |\cos s_k|,$$

which is obvious using $|\cos s_k|=|\cos(s_{k+1}-a_{k+1})|$

However, I am looking for a proof without using induction.

Any hints??

Comment: Someone said in this forum something like this: “*Any* statement about all integers involves induction.”

Comment: @MartinR  which one is it the one after base case line

Comment: Since $|\sin(x)|$ is concave for all $x$ ,$x$ a real number you can use Karamata's inequality .

Comment: @MartinR  it should be $cos s_n$ please see how $s_n$ has been defined. And for the other one it was a typo ihave fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: plese note the sigma does not include the $|cos s_i$ term

Comment: @MartinR  yes i should have !, hope it makes sense now

Comment: @c-love-garlic: $|\sin(x)|$ is concave on every interval $[n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$ but *not* on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\sum|\sin a_i|\ge\left|\sin\sum a_i\right|=|\sin s_n|$ from the Triangle Inequality and we know that $|\cos s_n|+|\sin s_n|\ge1$.

Comment: That's nice (but of course $\sum|\sin a_i|\ge\left|\sin\sum a_i\right|$ involves induction :)

Comment: @MartinR Fair point! Though since $n$ is finite I think we *could* get away with repeated iterations of the Triangle Inequality which somewhat bypass the formalities of induction...